# GtkDrawingArea with Cairo - how to make it scrollable

Tags: c, scroll, gtk, cairo

Followed is a small code to use `cairo` to draw something. The problem is that the canvas drawn by cairo is larger than the area of gtk's scrolled_window. But the scrolled_window doesn't scroll so I can only see the part of the canvas.

Any suggestion? My environment: MinGW + gtk2.10.11.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event) 
{
  cairo_t *cr;
  cr = gdk_cairo_create (widget->window);
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
  cairo_paint(cr);
  cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.42, 0.65, 0.80);
  cairo_set_line_width (cr,6);
  cairo_rectangle (cr, 30, 30, 100, 100);
  cairo_stroke (cr); 
  cairo_destroy(cr);
  return FALSE;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *sw;
  GtkWidget *cr;

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_policy((GtkWindow *)window, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
  sw = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL,NULL);
  gtk_widget_set_usize(sw, 100, 100);
  cr = gtk_drawing_area_new();

  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_CONTAINER(sw), cr);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), sw);

  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (cr, "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(draw_cb),  NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, when drawing you have two choices:

1. either you want the drawn content to adapt to the available size, and you use cairo_scale for that
2. or you use a scrolled view, as you're doing.

In case 2, Cairo has no way of knowing you're drawing out of bounds. And in some cases, drawing out of bounds is even what you want. So here, what is missing is setting the drawing area's size. This can be done using [gtk_widget_set_size_request](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-size-request).

Comment: Before I start to draw, I don't know the size of the graph, so I can't set the drawing area's size by `gtk_widget_size_request`.  According to your words, there is no way to make cairo scroll with the scrolled_window. It is really bad. It is often that the cairo graph is larger than the scrolled_window's area. To make it fit with the scrolled_window, I must scale the graph but it could be not large enough to see it clearly. No better way?

Comment: If you control the drawing, you know where you're drawing! Hence, you know the bounding rectangle of what you need to display. And you can then call `gtk_widget_size_request` with that. And if you choose to use scaling instead, the user is able to resize to a size that fits what he wants.

Comment: Think about how it works on a software like The GIMP. If you want to create a new image, you need to define a default size at first. The image won't grow if you try to draw outside the canvas. However, if you know you'll need to draw out of the canvas, you can just grow the canvas before drawing. That way the canvas adapts its size to the content.